# Logging framework for monotouch and monodroid

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Is there any logging framework for monotouch and monodroid?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're asking, but the Android.Util.Log class is available. See http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T:Android.Util.Log

The System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log class is available in both Monodroid and Monotouch. See
http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M:System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try Testflight for monotouch.

There you can upload your app for testing or install the TestFlight SDK into your app for logging or getting Feedback.

www.Testflightapp.com